# How to require .json file with module.exports in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

im used to creating .json files this way

```
module.exports = [
{"year":2007,"month":1,"startDate":"2007-01-01","endDate":"2007-01-31"},
{"year":2007,"month":2,"startDate":"2007-02-01","endDate":"2007-02-28"},
{"year":2007,"month":3,"startDate":"2007-03-01","endDate":"2007-03-31"},
]
```

I then require them like this.

```
var dates = require('./JSON/dates.json');
```

this has always worked in the past when i was working with nodejs and grunt to build websites. 
But now im using nodeJS to create a server app i get this message

SyntaxError: G:\Navision Reports\JS ReportServer\JSON\dates.json: Unexpected token message. I dont understand what's going on. It is working perfectly with .js files.

Please anyone knows why this no longer works? I know i could have a json object if i just remove var dates = require('./JSON/dates.json'); and make the file into one json object, but I'd really rather not reorganise all this data.

Comment: Ok Thanks, i will use dates.js instead. I understand that it's not a valid JSON object, im still a little puzzled as to why this used to work for me in the past though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't valid JSON file, you can check in any code formatter that it has syntax errors:

```
module.exports = [
{"year":2007,"month":1,"startDate":"2007-01-01","endDate":"2007-01-31"},
{"year":2007,"month":2,"startDate":"2007-02-01","endDate":"2007-02-28"},
{"year":2007,"month":3,"startDate":"2007-03-01","endDate":"2007-03-31"},
]
```

Please format your JSON in valid way and then require it or change `dates.json` to `dates.js`.

If you save file as `.json` you don't have to use `module.exports`, you actually can't, because node has built-in support for requiring `.json` files. You don't even have to use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: (in nodejs) these days you can `require` a json file by just refering to the name but leaving the `.json` off. for instance `const jsondata = require("./myjsonfile")` in vscode i don't get any intelisense for it, but it does work(there is probably an extension for that).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to save your file as *.js

```
require('./JSON/dates.js');
```

works fine.

Because with module.exports its not a well formed JSON any more; it is javascript

Answer (score 0):

If the contents of your file are just key value pair, you can just keep it in a JSON file and require it in your JS file.

For example:
If you filename is someConfig.json

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": {
        "label1": "value2",
        "label2": "value3"
    }
}
```

Now in your js file you can just do the following:

```
const myJSONFile = require("./someConfig.json");

console.log(myJSONFile.key2.label2); // value3
```